# Help with the proof of $P(x|z) = \sum_y P(x|y,z)P(y|z) $

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

This is the derivation in question:

[image]

My attempt:

[image]

I'm technically there however, I don't know why the summation y dissapears in the last part of my solution, I just forced it and assumed I was correct. I'd like some clarification of why the 'y' can just dissapear, or if that is not the case what else I should do to find the soltution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two things going on with these equalities. One thing is using the definition of a conditional distribution. You mentioned that you understand this, and why expanding these definitions leads terms to cancel out if they're shared in both the numerator and denominator of a fraction.

The second thing that is happening in most of these expressions, and this is the thing you seem to be interested in, is that when you write some joint probability mass function, "summing out" or "margining out" a variable "removes" that variable. This is a consequence of countable additivity of probability functions/measures. For your last equality, the probability that $X$ is $x$, and $Z$ is $z$ is the same as the probability that $X$ is $x$, and $Z$ is $z$ and $Y$ is $1$ PLUS the probability that $X$ is $x$, and $Z$ is $z$ and $Y$ is $2$ PLUS ... and so on.